# pre-code String Change in js single quotes to double quotes

Tags: javascript, html, pre

Hi I need to change this string in double quotes but I am not getting how to do

Right Now it is like

```
"&lt;iframe src='"+urlSrv+'&embedded=true'+ "' frameborder='0' scrolling='auto' width='100%' height='100%'&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;"
```

and output is

```
<iframe src='http://localhost:46030/Login/Appointment%20Booking/Home.aspx?clhid=717c043d-126f-4f57-910b-247a83d58801?embedded=true' frameborder='0' scrolling='auto' width='100%' height='1000'></iframe>
```

but I need to make it as

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:46030/Login/Appointment%20Booking/Home.aspx?clhid=717c043d-126f-4f57-910b-247a83d58801&embedded=true" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" width="100%" height="1000"></iframe>
```

the below script where I am Converting it

```
dvContSrvBtnCopy.className = "col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 padddiv";
                    dvContSrvBtnCopy.style.marginTop = "-2rem";
                    var pre = document.createElement('pre');
                    pre.className = 'precode';
                    var code = document.createElement('code');
                    if (type == "ServiceCatg") {
                        code.id = "txtFrameSrv_" + i;
                        code.innerHTML = '&lt;iframe src="'+urlSrv+'&embedded=true'+ '" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" width="100%" height="1000" &gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;';
                    }

                    pre.appendChild(code);
                    dvContSrv.appendChild(pre);
                    var btnCopy = document.createElement("button");
                    btnCopy.className = 'btnCOPYOnlineBkDynamic';
                    btnCopy.type = "button";
                    if (type == "ServiceCatg") {
                        btnCopy.id = "btnCopySrv_" + i;
                        btnCopy.setAttribute('onclick', "StaffSrvCrclCopy('" + btnCopy.id + "','ServiceCatg',true);");

                    }

                    var spnCopy = document.createElement("span");
                    spnCopy.className = 'copyDOOnlineBk';
                    btnCopy.appendChild(spnCopy);
                    dvContSrvBtnCopy.appendChild(btnCopy);
```

Comment: I don't entirely understand the question, where is the string coming from ?

Comment: Why are you using `&lt;` inside a JS string? You can have the actual symbols rather than the HTML entities...

Comment: it was not working by giving actual symbols it is giving the complete frame by itself

Comment: Can you add the JS where it converts the string into the HTML?

Comment: sure I will add it right now

Comment: I have added it @evolutionxbox

Comment: You have to use `<` and `>` otherwise it'll just output text and not an actual iframe.

Comment: yes thats wat i want i need output text not the iframe as i need to put it in pre code element sorry I misunderstood your question otherwise i would have told you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
'<iframe src="' + urlSrv + '" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" width="100%" height="1000"></iframe>'
```

I find it easiest to read HTML embedded in Javascript by wrapping it in single quotes, you can continue to use double quotes as normal in your HTML.

If you need to use single quotes in the html, you can escape them like this:

```
\'
```

Comment: To add to this, strings can be quoted using single or double quotes with no difference in JavaScript: `'my string'` is the same thing as `"my string"`. But using one character allows you to use the other one within the string.

Comment: yes you are right i did that just now only i got the answer by myself but thanks for helping much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want double codes, you could use escape symbol.

```
"&lt;iframe src=\"" + urlSrv + "\"&embedded=\"true\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"auto\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;"
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you already have the single-quoted string and want to replace the single with double quotes, you can use `string.replace()`:

```
var s2 = s.replace(/'/g, "\"");
```

As for a complete example: you have these two `pre`-Tags:

```
<pre id="content1"></pre>
<pre id="content2"></pre>
```

Then the following Javascript will fill the first one with the single-quoted string, and the second one with the double-quoted one:

```
var urlSrv = "http://localhost/";
var s = "&lt;iframe src='"+urlSrv+'&embedded=true'+ "' frameborder='0' scrolling='auto' width='100%' height='100%'&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;";

var el = document.getElementById("content1");
el.innerHTML = s;

// Here we replace all the single quotes with double qutes
var s2 = s.replace(/'/g, "\"");

var el2 = document.getElementById("content2");
el2.innerHTML = s2;
```

[See here for a running example](https://jsfiddle.net/mzxom55p/)